# Can using server-side scripting delimiters (<% %>) cause compilations during runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, etw

I am occasionally getting "Application compilation is starting." event in my Event Log and I can't identify what's causing it. I think I may try this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-etw-tracing.aspx - but before I do that I was curious if I can identify the problem without starting to mess with something unknown.

I have used <%= %> and <%# %> tags throughout the app so I am wondering if this is what's causing the problems. On couple spots I have embedded C# code (using ) so that may add to it?

Precompiling the app is also valid choice for me, I just don't want to end in position in which I need execute precompilation command on the server every time I upload some changes to the server. Currently on my dev machine I've followed advices from this link - http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/05/compiling-aspx-templates-using.html - and it does awesome job as it allows me to identify errors in C# code in .aspx pages during build in Visual Studio. However, I presume precompilation results are not stored in my website directory (and won't be published when I use Publish option).

Ideally, I want to stay in position I am with default Web Application model with addition of automatically running compilation as soon as I upload changed .aspx or .ascx over FTP (not waiting for user's http request). Am I asking too much, or is this possible to setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research it seems it can.

Because nobody responded I'll accept this as answer.